# NIS netgroup map empty for nis client

Tags: sles, nis

We had a NIS master server disaster and an outdated backup for it, but some slaves.
I've been put in charge without any NIS knowledge so far except a few basics.

I've dumped every map via ypcat from an old slave, set up a SLES11 machine, added these files to /var/yp/ypfiles, pointed yast2 nis_server at it and set up the entire machinery, including two new machines as slaves - also SLES11.

I then took an older machine, pointed that at my new NIS-Server and tried auth. Once I found out you had to activate shadow passwords for some reasons - and the old maps were like 10+ years old without shadow passwords, auth worked so far.

**However, netgroup did not work on another machine. ypcat netgroup gave me an empty line, ypcat netgroup.byhost no line at all, same for .byuser.**

I've added +:::::: to the end of the empty /etc/netgroup without any difference. I've run make in /var/yp - no chance.

/etc/nsswitch from the server:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat nis

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files dns

services:       files nis
protocols:      files
rpc:            files
ethers:         files
netmasks:       files
netgroup:       nis
publickey:      files

bootparams:     files
automount:      files
aliases:        files nis
shadow:         compat
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf from the test NIS client:

```
passwd:     files nis
shadow:     files nis
group:      files nis

hosts:      files nis dns

bootparams: files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
netgroup:   files nis
publickey:  files
automount:  files
aliases:    files
```

So yeah, why does ypcat netgroup not return anything on the new server, but everything via an old slave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently SLES11 uses two source folders to generate its data. Partly the one you specifiy during the yast setup, and partly the ones in /etc. netgroup, along with other files, are being pulled from /etc. Files like passwd, group and shadow are not.

Thus the confusion of the empty netgroup. That's why adding +:::::: to /etc/netgroup had no effect, either.

To correct this behaviour, edit in /var/yp/Makefile

```
YPSRCDIR = /etc
```

to

```
YPSRCDIR = /foo/your/ypfiles)
```

**Note**: YPPWDDIR gets its source dir from some scripting. Copying that line to YPSRCDIR might be a cleaner solution.

Also, this solution is a bit dirty alltogether, since it is a restore from a broken NIS master without backup, only from ypcat slaveserver dumps and everything placed into a single folder on a different OS than before... I had to reconstruct the netgroup file entirely, using a far outdated version of it from a previous spontaneous copy of it I had made ages ago. Took me a few days due to the sheer length, even though Notepad++ helped me alot there.

**Moral of the story:**
Proper Backups and checks on them are really REALLY important.